# What does this probability formula mean

Tags: probability

$$ P(B\cap C|A)=P(C|B \cap A)P(B|A)$$
I know that if we expand out the right hand side we get the left hand side, but what does this formula mean intuitively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right side is letting the event $B$ happen first (given that $A$ has happened), this is the probability $P(B|A)$; and then $C$ happen after $B$ has happened (and $A$ has happened), this is the probability $P(C | B\cap A)$.

Left side is considering the both events at once.